# Devices and Printers control panel, desktop is categorized as a laptop

Tags: windows-7, metadata, control-panel

I have a Dell OptiPlex 790 tower running Windows 7.  When I go to the "Devices and Printers" control panel, and right-click my computer's name, it says under Device Information, "Categories: Laptop computer".

Why has it determined that my computer is a laptop?  Does this effect anything other than the icon there?

Comment: I didn't even know that dialog existed!  A few similar questions from a quick Google basically say try updating the chipset drivers, or ask Dell.  Personally, I don't think it has any effect on the PC at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an old and absolutely harmless bug in Windows.

To my great surprise I discovered that I have the same problem on my own Dell desktop.

I have therefore found and used this old Fixit (using IE) dating from 2011,
but which fixed the problem
and transformed my computer from "Laptop computer" into "Tower computer" :
[On Windows 7 icons for WSD devices may show up incorrectly as a different class under Devices and Printers](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2403006/en-us).
This article does not mention any side-effects of this bug, so this wrong icon
seems to be the only side-effect of this bug, limited to Devices and Printers.

If you don't like the icon that Windows assigns to your computer,
and frankly the "Tower computer" image that I now have looks more like an external hard disk, you could follow this advice :
[Windows 7: Devices and Printers - Change Device Icons with Custom Icons](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/224162-devices-printers-change-device-icons-custom-icons.html).

[image]

My own recommendation is to leave this alone - the "Laptop computer" icon is much nicer.

Comment: Yep, that fixed it.  I don't believe the "cause" they give applies in my situation--my computer had a clean Windows installation done long after 2010.  I have many other computers in my organization with the same problem.  I'm marking this as an answer, but I'm still in search of the cause--the "why" part of my question.

Comment: If I had one cent for every "why" I asked about Windows ...

Answer (score 0):

I can answer half of this now.

The category comes from the [DeviceInfo XML Schema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff541135.aspx) (`DeviceInfo.xml` file) and "device-related user interfaces in Windows display this detailed information to users".  This *implies* it's for the GUI only, and not used by the system for anything.

But it doesn't explain why it's using the wrong category, or where my computer's DeviceInfo.xml file came from.